# Opera Dragonfly in each window

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

How do I get two separate Dragonfly instances in two Opera windows? Right now when I try to load Dragonfly in the second window, whilst it's already opened in the first one, Opera will focus on the first window and close Dragonfly there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it currently isn’t possible due to the architecture of the Scope protocol that Opera Dragonfly uses to talk to the browser.

It is a known issue however.